# How do I set up a wireless guest network

Tags: networking, wifi, guest

I have 2 wireless routers and a wired router. I need to have a secured wireless network (i have up and running) and i would like a wireless network for customers to use and not see our internal network computers and only acces the internet. Setting up a basic wep security on the customers wireless router is not a problem. I just want to keep the apartment dwellers from free wireless.

How do i configure the second wireless router for the customers. Nothing is connected to the wired part of this router. Can i just change the ip or subnet to accomplish this or is it more involved?

Comment: One option is just to buy a basic 2nd domestic internet connection that is likely to come with a wireless router.   This does have a monthly charge, but gives you a backup if you main connection fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just changing the subnet will not hide the private network, If I were you I would just connect it directly your modem and not into any switch or router that is connected to your secure network.

In some cases this may not be possible, so I would highly recommend using a computer as a router to separate these networks. Ideally it would have three network interfaces. For example eth0 for inet, eth1 for privatenet and eth2 for guestnet. Then you could use iptables to separate the networks and even if you wanted to, prioritize your traffic over the guests so that they wont waste your bandwidth.

Some good tutorials would be:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/

(a firewall generator) http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/

Hope that helps,
RayQuang

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly that, with the added wrinkle that I wanted to use the public wireless for my trusted clients too, so I layered a VPN on top, plus some traffic-shaping so that people using guest wireless couldn't use all of my interent bandwidth.

I wrote it up at http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/home-wireless.html , in some detail; it may be of interest/use to you.

Answer (score 0):

IF your wireless router supports linux, you can use openwrt or dd-wrt, it has all you need: shaping, NAT + firewall to protect local network, encryption. There are a few other distro made for hotspots like: hotspot, chillispot.

First tutorial in my searches is [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/wifi_hotspot_setup).

HTH